# Windows Authentication in .NET Core doesn't show prompt in Chrome

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 with Asp.Net Core 3.1 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I'm building a website that shows different views based on the Authentication of the user: if an user authenticates with his Active Directory credentials then he can see more things on the Webpages otherwise he can see basic info.

So I combined the use of the Windows Authentication and Anonymouse Authentication setting both to TRUE in the **launchSetting.json**:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50548",
      "sslPort": 44312
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Name_Of_The_Project": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

In the controller I've created the Login method:

```
// GET: /Config/Login
public IActionResult Login()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm in Login (GET)");

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
    return View();
}
```

It returns me this View (Login.cshtml):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <h3>You are logged in</h3> 
}
else
{
    <h3>Please insert your Windows credentials to login</h3>
    <div>Click the link and a window will appear</div>
    <br />
    <a href="/Config/LoginWindows">Login</a>
}
```

I use "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" in the Views to check if the user is already authenticated to show them the right info.
So in this case if the user is not authenticated, a button will show up which gets handled by this method in the controller:

```
[Authorize]
// GET: /Config/LoginWindows
public IActionResult LoginWindows()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm in LoginWindows (GET)");

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Because it has the [Authorize] attribute, it triggers the Windows Authentication prompt where I have to put my credentials. If they're correct, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be set to TRUE and then I can see all the right contents in the pages.

I tried configuring **Startup.cs** both for IIS Express and Kestel web servers and launching the website using both of them:
In the options of the play button in Visual studio if I choose IIS Express will use the IIS Express proxy, if I choose Name_Of_The_Project Kestel will be used directly.

**IIS Express**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // IIS/IIS Express
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Config/LoginFailed"); // first asks me the credentials then if it fails, i'm redirected to the other page
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**Kestel**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // KESTREL
        services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddNegotiate();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Config/LoginFailed"); // first asks me the credentials then if it fails, i'm redirected to the other page
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**The problem**

My problem is that in both configurations only Microsoft Edge has the right behavior: I click the button in the login page, the prompt shows up, I put my credentials, the page reloads saying I'm logged in.

In Google Chrome I click the button in the Login page and it automaticly authenticates me without showing any prompt. After some time when browsing through the website, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns to FALSE so I need to click the login button another time.

In Firefox the prompt shows up but it doesn't accept my credentials so the prompt reloads everytime till the webpage shows me I don't have the Authorization to access.

I've followed the Microsoft Docs:

[Configure Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

[Simple Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Eventually, I took another approach to authenticate the user.

Comment: That's sad. :(  But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ie internet options > Security > Trusted Sites add your website url example:http://localhost:6000 or http://foo.bar.web:7000